# Xcode 9.2 / iOS 11 / Can't find folder

Tags: ios, xcode

Apple recently demanded I upgrade my iPhone to the latest iOS version (11.2), and, as usual, Xcode then refused to connect to it unless I upgraded Xcode, which, of course, I could only do, if I upgraded my version of Mac OS.

So, after wasting half a day downloading and installing updates, I'm now on Xcode 9.2, and my code, which built beautifully before, fails to build with an error of:

```
    ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/
Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk/
Developer/Library/Frameworks'
```

(Note: I've added spaces in that folder path myself, to make it readable here.)

The error message is true though.

If I attempt to go into that folder, I can get as far as the **iPhoneOS11.2.sdk** folder, then there's no **Developer** sub-folder in it.

[image: iOS 11 problem]

I have Googled this problem, and lots of people recommend checking your "Library Search Paths" and "Framework Search Path" settings...  but in my case, both of these were blank.  I didn't have *any* folders specified in my build settings.

Interestingly, in that screenshot above, I noticed that the **System** folder does have a **Library\Frameworks** subfolder so (out of desperation) I copied the **System** folder into a folder called **Developer**.

Ridiculously, this seems to have fixed the problem, but surely I'm missing something here...

Has anyone else had this problem, specifically since upgrading Xcode ?

After making this change to the folder structure, I did still have 1 other error.  Xcode was now complaining that:

```
embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later
```

Again, this error hadn't appeared before I upgraded Xcode, but the fix was to change the iOS Deployment Target in my "Project" build settings and in each of the Target build settings.

[image: Build Settings]

What really bugs me about Xcode is that I don't want/need any of the new iOS 11 functionality.  This is a legacy in-house app, which we've been using since iOS 7.  This stuff should *just build*, after an Xcode update, but with each release, we get new problems, as obscure as the ones highlighted here.

This Xcode stuff is truly terrible...  please can I go back to my warm-and-cosy Microsoft environment now...?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use your old Xcode to support 11.2 
To support you need to run below command:

sudo ln -s PATH_OF_NEW_XCODE_DEVICESupport_TO_11.2 PATH_OF_EXISTING_XCODE_DEVICESupport

Example:

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/11.0 /Applications/Xcode821.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

Comment: Thanks for this advice.  But seriously, if you don't do this, Xcode thinks "directory not found" is a good error message to help developers get around this issue ?  This stuff is dreadful...

Comment: Try to create New App in New Xcode and If it works fine then your project may be having some Build Settings problem